# При перезагрузке страницы сохранить и вывести нужный элемент option

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

```
<select name="page-dropdown"
    onchange=' window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();'>

<?php
$pages = get_pages();
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $option = '<option selected value="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '">';
    $option .= $page->post_title;
    $option .= '</option>';
    echo $option;
}
?>
</select>
```

Вот такой код выводит все ссылки на страницы WordPress в select. После выбора перенаправляет на нужную страницу. Надо сделать так, чтобы в seleсt передавалась текущая страница. Сейчас после перезагрузки выводится самый верхний option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, можно попробовать так:

```
<?php
$page_id = get_the_ID();
$pages = get_pages();
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $option = '<option ' . selected($page_id, $page->ID) . ' value="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '">';
    $option .= $page->post_title;
    $option .= '</option>';
    echo $option;
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Опередил ))) Я бы только добавил, что это сработает, если код находится внутри главного цикла WordPress.

Comment: СПАСИБО !!! КУДА ДОНАТИТЬ ? ))))

Comment: @Дмитрий http://www.donationalerts.ru/r/denisco :D

Comment: Закинул на пивас  )  Подписался на канал и группу ВК

Comment: @Дмитрий Спасибо и добро пожаловать! :)